# All javascript stops working on my child template when I perform an AJAX call to change the queryset

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, django-templates

I have a `comments.html` child template that looks like this:

```
<div class="commentsContainer">
    {% for comment in comment_list %} 

    ...


        {{ comment.text }} 

    ...

    {%  endfor %}

</div>
```

When I click on a button I call this AJAX function:

```
$('.comments_new').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/new_comments/',
        data: {
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('.commentsContainer ').replaceWith(data);
        }
    })
});
```

which calls this view to change the queryset (the inital queryset is `comment_list = Comment.objects.filter().order_by('-score__upvotes')`:

```
def new_comments(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        comment_list = Comment.objects.filter().order_by('-timestamp')
        html = render_to_string('comments.html', {'comment_list': comment_list})
        return HttpResponse(html)
```

This successfully swaps the querysets, however for some reason no javascript works on the newly loaded template/queryset. I even tried just using a simple `.css()` jquery function but it doesn't work either. Only regular css works. Can somebody tell me why this happens and how I can fix it?

EDIT:

I'm also getting this error in my terminal when the call is made: `UserWarning: A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context did not provide the value.  This is usually caused by not using RequestContext.`

edit2: new call using `JsonResponse`

```
def new_comments(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        comment_list = Comment.objects.filter().order_by('-timestamp')
        html = {'comment_list': comment_list}
        return JsonResponse(html)
```

`raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")`

`TypeError: <QuerySet [<Comment: qwdjkqbwkdjbqd>, <Comment: woeifnoeinfw>, <Comment: example>, <Comment: enlaasd>, <Comment: aelanfaf>, <Comment: asdasda>]> is not JSON serializable`

Comment: your response is html?

Comment: Yes? `comments.html` extends the base template which has the `base.js` javascript file.

Comment: not , the respons f ajax  url: '/new_comments/', is html content?

Comment: Yes `render_to_string` converted it to html content

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas:

1. I would change your HttpResponse with a [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects). Should not be a problem, but who knows (I await feedback of you for this). Remember to return a dict with a key that has the new HTML as value.
2. You should swap`replaceWith()` to `html()`. You're setting new HTML, so it will be easier to prevent unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Just tried `JsonResponse` and i'm getting a `raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")`. the code is in my edit.

Comment: Yeah, you're trying to make automatic serialization, and Django doesn't do that. You just passed the queryset result to the dict (make a `raise TypeError(html["comment_list"])` to see what I say). You need to do something like this: `for obj in comment_list: html["comment_list"].append({"id": obj.id, "text": obj.text, ...})`

Comment: Can you explain what that's doing? I'm writing your code but i'm not exactly sure what the goal is. `html = {'comment_list': comment_list}`
        `for comment in comment_list:`
            `html['comment_list'].append({'id': comment.id, 'text': comment.comment_text, 'user': comment.user})`

        return JsonResponse(html)

Comment: Ah, my bad, sorry. Just do `html = {"comment_list": render_to_string('comments.html', {'comment_list': comment_list}) }`, and later in the AJAX callback `data.comment_list`. Should work now. Will check you tomorrow, now I need to go bed, awakening soon for work.

Comment: No worries but do I keep the for loop you posted?

Comment: No no, just set the value to `render_to_string(..)` result

Comment: Yeah, just change the return with `JsonResponse({"html": render_to_string('comments.html', {'comment_list': comment_list})}, safe=True)`. The `safe` arg lets you render without character problems later in the JS. Sorry for the inconvenience, bad thinking of me yesterday.

Comment: Just tried that and still the same outcome - data successfully loads but JS not working

Comment: I would like to continue, but I don't have enough rep for chat, and I'm getting warnings of avoiding extended discussions. Check the console log, code some pure JS from the console to test, check what are the differences internally between the old and new elements... your code seems right, has to be something else.